# Windows 10: best way to update live tile or display notifications

Tags: .net, windows-10, uwp

I'm trying to understand what is the best way to update my live tile.

From this article https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779721.aspx

Windows 10 has now 4 types of notifications:

- Local: when app is running
- Scheduled: creates schedule e.g. 1 week in advance
- Periodic: pools some cloud service via URL
- Push: Windows Push Notification Services (WNS)

5th way would be to register a Background task that would update Live Tile at a schedule which seems not "approved" way? since Microsoft did not mention it and task is registered generally first time app runs where user is not asked if they want it to run and at what frequency...

6th way potentially is there a way to combine Periodic updates via StartPeriodicUpdate(URL) and by providing a link to App Service/Background Task? (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt187314.aspx) that will handle tile update without any cloud service running?

Comment: I would expect the *best* way to update your live tile would be one of those 4 options. Is there any reason why any of these 4 options do not meet your requirements?

Answer (score 0):

I am using 5th method for three years already, and it is working well. Draw Tile image in background task (Using XamlRenderingBackgroundTask class), and set it as live tile.